# Modal pop-up is displayed in angular

Tags: angular, popup, angular5

Here Modal pop-up is not working, where it only displays a blur screen but the content inside the modal pop-up is not displayed. Where I have displayed it at the end of the component.ts file and when I edit the code inside or outside the mat-card it throws the same error. Please edit the following changes i the pop-op modal.

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
    <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="35" fxFlex.md="45">

        <mat-card class="product-image">
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="openZoomViewer()" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-md><mat-icon>fullscreen</mat-icon></button>
            <img *ngIf="image" [src]="image" (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)" (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave($event)"/>
        </mat-card>       

        <div class="small-carousel"> 
            <div class="swiper-container" [swiper]="config">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper"> 
                    <!-- <div *ngFor="let image of product?.images" gFor="let image of product?.images" class="swiper-slide"> -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <mat-card (click)="selectImage(image)" class="p-1">
                            <img src="assets/images/products/keyboard/1-small.png" class="swiper-lazy"/>
                            <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
                        </mat-card>
                        <!-- <mat-card (click)="selectImage(image)" class="p-1">
                            <img src="assets/images/products/keyboard/1-small.png" class="swiper-lazy"/>
                            <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
                        </mat-card> -->
                    </div>     
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <mat-card (click)="selectImage(image)" class="p-1">
                            <img src="assets/images/products/keyboard/1-small.png" class="swiper-lazy"/>
                            <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
                        </mat-card>      
                        </div>         
                </div>
                <button mat-icon-button class="swiper-button-prev swipe-arrow"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon></button>
                <button mat-icon-button class="swiper-button-next swipe-arrow"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon></button> 
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="45" fxFlex.md="55" ngClass.gt-sm="px-3 m-0" ngClass.sm="mt-2" ngClass.xs="mt-2">

        <div #zoomViewer fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-md>
            <mat-card *ngIf="zoomImage" class="zoom-viewer mat-elevation-z18" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + zoomImage + ')'}">
            </mat-card>
        </div>

        <h2>{{product?.name}}</h2>
        <div class="py-1 lh">
            <!-- <p><span class="text-muted fw-500">Category: </span><span>{{ ( appService.Data.categories | filterById : product?.categoryId )?.name }}</span></p>
            <p><span class="text-muted fw-500">Availibility: </span><span>{{ (product?.availibilityCount > 0) ? 'In stock':'Unavailable'}}</span></p> -->
        </div>                 
        <!-- <div class="py-1">
            <app-rating [ratingsCount]="product?.ratingsCount" [ratingsValue]="product?.ratingsValue" [direction]="'row'"></app-rating>
        </div> -->
        <p class="py-1 text-muted lh">{{product?.description}}</p>

        <div class="divider mt-1"></div>
        <h2 class="py-2 new-price" *ngIf="product?.newPrice || product2?.newPrice">{{product?.currency}}{{product?.newPrice}}</h2> 

        <!-- <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" class="details text-muted py-1">
            <div *ngIf="product?.color" class="color">
                <span class="fw-500">Select Color:</span>
                <button mat-raised-button *ngFor="let color of product?.color" [style.background]="color">&nbsp;</button>              
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="product?.size" class="size" ngClass.xs="mt-1">
                <span class="fw-500">Select Size:</span>
                <button mat-raised-button *ngFor="let size of product?.size">{{size}}</button>
            </div>
        </div> -->

         <div class="py-1 text-muted" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent" *ngIf="product?.newPrice || product2?.newPrice" (click)="addToCart(product)"><mat-icon>shopping_cart</mat-icon> Add to Cart</button> 
<!--             <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Add to wishlist" (click)="addToWishList(product)"><mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon></button>
 -->       
 <button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Request Pricing" color="accent" *ngIf="!(product?.newPrice || product2?.newPrice)">Request Pricing</button>  
</div>
<sc-modal id="modal-1" class="default" #modal>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        This my title
        <button class="sc-modal-close" (click)="closeModal('modal-1');"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h1>A Custom Modal Name</h1>
        <p>
          Home page text: <input type="text" />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
  </sc-modal>

  <button (click)="openModal('modal-1')">Open Modal</button>
        <div class="divider"></div>

        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" class="text-muted py-1">
            <!-- <button mat-button><mat-icon>mail_outline</mat-icon> Email to a Friend</button> -->
            <!-- <button mat-raised-button color="accent"><mat-icon>cart</mat-icon> Add to Cart</button>             -->
            <!-- <button mat-raised-button color="accent" *ngIf="product?.availibilityCount > 0" (click)="addToCart(product)"><mat-icon>shopping_cart</mat-icon> Add to Cart</button> -->

            <!-- <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>share</mat-icon></button> -->

            <!-- <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Add to wishlist" (click)="addToWishList(product)"><mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon></button> -->

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div fxLayout="row wrap" class="mt-2">
    <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="78" fxFlex.md="74">
        <mat-card> 
            <mat-tab-group [@.disabled]="true" [selectedIndex]="0">       
                <mat-tab label="Description">
                    <div class="full-desc lh">
                        <!-- <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id nulla metus. Maecenas commodo turpis dui, porttitor tincidunt enim mollis a. Curabitur eu velit mi. Nullam congue turpis id metus sollicitudin, id cursus nulla laoreet. Proin commodo eu felis at malesuada. Nulla ac facilisis justo, eget vulputate ex. Nulla nec laoreet nulla. Cras auctor leo at diam congue, quis convallis urna pulvinar. Nunc ut mi nulla. Nunc ligula massa, vulputate sed scelerisque sit amet, dapibus semper est. Sed sed blandit turpis. Vestibulum id porttitor ligula, at iaculis ligula. Pellentesque vel tellus sit amet mauris aliquet bibendum id et lorem.</p> -->
                        <ul class="px-2 mt-1">
                            <li>Expose SolidWorks platform into the BIM environment.</li>
                            <li>Easy transfer of SolidWorks model to Revit, other BIM and mechanical software.</li>
                            <li>Control and safe data transfer.</li>
                            <li>User friendly and availability of more export options.</li>
                            <li>Reduction of design error by more than 50%.</li>
                            <li>Reduce the design time and effort more than 70%.</li>
                            <li>Better design quality.</li>
                            <li>Faster design iterations.</li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- <p class="mt-1">Duis eu felis ultricies urna pharetra efficitur nec non elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur posuere eu justo eget mollis. Sed semper accumsan urna vel rutrum. Nulla condimentum quis lacus ut semper. Quisque at massa pretium, porta ligula ut, rutrum elit. Pellentesque et orci sit amet dolor laoreet tempor sed eu sem. Morbi lacinia pellentesque tellus euismod eleifend.</p>
                        <p class="mt-1">Quisque fringilla eros id ligula luctus, a gravida augue sodales. Sed eget augue ut lectus condimentum volutpat. Morbi quis nunc viverra, gravida arcu quis, varius metus. Praesent tincidunt ipsum est, quis molestie ligula efficitur ut. Nunc interdum erat eu tortor maximus suscipit. Vivamus nec laoreet dui. Nullam dignissim laoreet metus quis pretium.</p> -->
                    </div>
                </mat-tab>
                <mat-tab label="How it Works?">
                    <div class="full-desc lh">
                        <!-- <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        <ul class="px-2 mt-1">
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                            <li>Aenean vehicula, tortor gravida elementum tincidunt, justo lorem vestibulum ex, eget egestas arcu tellus in magna. Vivamus gravida, ipsum vel luctus luctus, nisi felis vestibulum est, nec interdum tellus leo quis tellus. Sed sit amet convallis enim, in laoreet orci.</li>
                            <li>Donec et elit at nulla congue interdum sit amet varius erat.</li>
                            <li>Nulla sit amet risus pellentesque, dignissim massa ut, dignissim arcu.</li>
                            <li>Morbi dapibus ligula at faucibus tempus. Aenean vehicula, tortor gravida elementum tincidunt, justo lorem vestibulum ex, eget egestas arcu tellus in magna. Vivamus gravida, ipsum vel luctus luctus, nisi felis vestibulum est, nec interdum tellus leo quis tellus. Sed sit amet convallis enim, in laoreet orci.</li>
                            <li>Nunc sodales justo ut nisi euismod, quis condimentum leo varius.</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="px-2 mt-1">
                            <li>Phasellus eu justo dictum, varius eros ut, posuere sapien.</li>
                            <li>Nulla eu erat sit amet enim lobortis rhoncus.</li>
                            <li>Etiam eu mauris in massa convallis ornare non id ex.</li>
                            <li>Nam sagittis augue at pretium pharetra.</li>
                            <li>Sed a sem id massa egestas porta a sit amet felis.</li>
                            <li>Duis aliquam urna in sapien cursus consequat. Aenean vehicula, tortor gravida elementum tincidunt, justo lorem vestibulum ex, eget egestas arcu tellus in magna. Vivamus gravida, ipsum vel luctus luctus, nisi felis vestibulum est, nec interdum tellus leo quis tellus. Sed sit amet convallis enim, in laoreet orci.</li>
                        </ul> -->
                      <!--   <iframe width="1000" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yPWHxsKManI?rel=0&showinfo=0">
                        </iframe> -->
                             <iframe width="100%" height="600" [src]="product.yURL | safe" ></iframe>
                    </div>

               </mat-tab>
                <!-- <mat-tab label="Reviews">
                    <div class="full-desc lh">
                        <mat-list class="reviews">
                            <mat-list-item class="h-100 py-1">
                                <img matListAvatar [src]="'assets/images/avatars/avatar-1.png'" alt="image" class="review-author">
                                <p matLine fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                                    <span class="fw-500">Bruno Vespa</span> 
                                    <mat-icon class="text-muted px-1" matTooltip="Dissatisfied" matTooltipPosition="after">sentiment_dissatisfied</mat-icon>
                                </p>
                                <p matLine class="text-muted"><small>13 January, 2018 at 7:09</small></p>
                                <p matLine class="text">Integer id eros et mi fringilla imperdiet. In dictum turpis eget magna viverra condimentum. Ut malesuada interdum ultrices. Proin tristique sem pellentesque, posuere dui in, maximus magna. Aenean vehicula, tortor gravida elementum tincidunt, justo lorem vestibulum ex, eget egestas arcu tellus in magna.</p>
                            </mat-list-item>
                            <mat-list-item class="h-100 py-1">
                                <img matListAvatar [src]="'assets/images/avatars/avatar-2.png'" alt="image" class="review-author">
                                <p matLine fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                                    <span class="fw-500">Julia Aniston</span> 
                                    <mat-icon class="text-muted px-1" matTooltip="Very Satisfied" matTooltipPosition="after">sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
                                </p>
                                <p matLine class="text-muted"><small>04 February, 2018 at 10:22</small></p>
                                <p matLine class="text">Nulla accumsan, lacus sed suscipit rutrum, turpis augue accumsan metus, in accumsan urna mi vehicula lorem. Pellentesque semper nibh vitae augue placerat finibus. Nulla sed porttitor nunc, quis tristique sem. Quisque in varius nisl. Integer turpis lorem, ultricies sed sem nec, commodo molestie arcu. Nulla finibus ex tortor, et suscipit magna semper consectetur. Cras sit amet metus dui. Maecenas eget dui at ex varius malesuada vel non felis.</p>
                            </mat-list-item>
                            <mat-list-item class="h-100 py-1">
                                <img matListAvatar [src]="'assets/images/avatars/avatar-3.png'" alt="image" class="review-author">
                                <p matLine fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                                    <span class="fw-500">Andy Warhol</span> 
                                    <mat-icon class="text-muted px-1" matTooltip="Neutral" matTooltipPosition="after">sentiment_neutral</mat-icon>
                                </p>
                                <p matLine class="text-muted"><small>14 February, 2018 at 11:10</small></p>
                                <p matLine class="text">Pellentesque hendrerit vel turpis aliquam placerat. Suspendisse ullamcorper congue feugiat. Etiam gravida metus ac massa posuere venenatis. Pellentesque vehicula lobortis dolor, ac pretium dolor maximus quis. Fusce vitae iaculis mauris, quis posuere ex. Mauris vitae convallis nibh. Etiam eget enim at orci interdum maximus nec in ante.</p>
                            </mat-list-item>
                        </mat-list>

                        <h3 class="mt-2">LEAVE YOUR REVIEW</h3>
                        <div class="divider"></div>
                        <p class="mt-2 text-muted">Your email address will not be published. Required fields are marked *</p>
                        <h3 fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="mt-2">
                            <span>Your Rating:</span>
                            <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Very Dissatisfied" matTooltipPosition="above"><mat-icon class="mat-icon-lg">sentiment_very_dissatisfied</mat-icon></button>
                            <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Dissatisfied" matTooltipPosition="above"><mat-icon class="mat-icon-lg">sentiment_dissatisfied</mat-icon></button>
                            <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Neutral" matTooltipPosition="above"><mat-icon class="mat-icon-lg">sentiment_neutral</mat-icon></button>
                            <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Satisfied" matTooltipPosition="above"><mat-icon class="mat-icon-lg">sentiment_satisfied</mat-icon></button>
                            <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Very Satisfied" matTooltipPosition="above"><mat-icon class="mat-icon-lg">sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon></button>
                        </h3>

                        <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" fxLayout="row wrap">
                            <div fxFlex="100" class="px-1 mt-1">
                                <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                                    <textarea matInput placeholder="Your review" formControlName="review" required></textarea>
                                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.review.errors?.required">Review is required</mat-error>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" class="px-1 mt-2">
                                <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                                    <input matInput placeholder="Your name" formControlName="name" required>
                                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.name.errors?.required">Name is required</mat-error>
                                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.name.hasError('minlength')">Name isn't long enough, minimum of 4 characters</mat-error>
                                </mat-form-field> 
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" class="px-1 mt-2">
                                <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                                    <input matInput placeholder="Your email" formControlName="email" required>
                                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.email.errors?.required">Email is required</mat-error>
                                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.email.hasError('invalidEmail')">Invalid email address</mat-error>
                                </mat-form-field> 
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex="100" class="mt-2 text-center w-100">
                                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">SUBMIT REVIEW</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>


                    </div>
                </mat-tab> -->
            </mat-tab-group>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
  <!--   <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="22" fxFlex.md="26" ngClass.gt-sm="pl-3" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x320/EEEEEE/9E9E9E/?text=Banner%201" alt="" class="mw-100 d-block">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x320/EEEEEE/9E9E9E/?text=Banner%202" alt="" class="mw-100 d-block mt-3">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x320/EEEEEE/9E9E9E/?text=Banner%203" alt="" class="mw-100 d-block mt-3">
    </div> -->
</div>

<div class="py-2 mt-2">
    <h2>Related Products</h2>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <app-products-carousel [products]="relatedProducts"></app-products-carousel>
</div>
```

And my component.ts file is

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { SwiperConfigInterface, SwiperDirective } from 'ngx-swiper-wrapper';
import { Data, AppService } from '../../../app.service';
import { Product } from "../../../app.models";
import { emailValidator } from '../../../theme/utils/app-validators';
import { ProductZoomComponent } from './product-zoom/product-zoom.component';
import { ModalService, ModalComponent } from 'angular-5-popup';

declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.scss']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('zoomViewer') zoomViewer;
  @ViewChild("modal") modal: ModalComponent;
  public config: SwiperConfigInterface={};
  public product: Product;
    pdfUrl: any;
  public image: any;
    id: any;
  public zoomImage: any;
  private sub: any;
  public form: FormGroup;
  public relatedProducts: Array<Product>;

  constructor(public appService:AppService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public dialog: MatDialog, public formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {      
    this.sub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => { 
      this.getProductById(params['id']);this.id=params['id'];

    }); 



    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      'review': [null, Validators.required],            
      'name': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])],
      'email': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, emailValidator])]
    }); 
    this.getRelatedProducts();  

    $(document).ready(function(){
      var $videoSrc;  
      $('.video-btn').click(function() {
          $videoSrc = $(this).data( "src" );
      });
      console.log($videoSrc);
      $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1" ); 
    })       
    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
      // a poor man's stop video
      $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc); 
  })
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.config = {
      observer: false,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 10,      
      keyboard: true,
      navigation: true,
      pagination: false,       
      loop: false, 
      preloadImages: false,
      lazy: true, 
      breakpoints: {
        480: {
          slidesPerView: 2
        },
        600: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public getProductById(id){
    this.appService.getProductById(id).subscribe(data=>{

      this.product = data;
      console.log("this.product",this.product)
      this.image = data.images[0].medium;
      this.zoomImage = data.images[0].big;
      setTimeout(() => { 
        this.config.observer = true;
       // this.directiveRef.setIndex(0);
      });
    });
  }

  public getRelatedProducts(){
    this.appService.getProducts('related').subscribe(data => {
      this.relatedProducts = data;
    })
  }



  public selectImage(image){
    //this.image = image.medium;
    this.zoomImage = image.big;
  }

  public onMouseMove(e){
    if(window.innerWidth >= 1280){
      var image, offsetX, offsetY, x, y, zoomer;
      image = e.currentTarget; 
      offsetX = e.offsetX;
      offsetY = e.offsetY;
      x = offsetX/image.offsetWidth*100;
      y = offsetY/image.offsetHeight*100;
      zoomer = this.zoomViewer.nativeElement.children[0];
      if(zoomer){
        zoomer.style.backgroundPosition = x + '% ' + y + '%';
        zoomer.style.display = "block";
        zoomer.style.height = image.height + 'px';
        zoomer.style.width = image.width + 'px';
      }
    }
  }

  public onMouseLeave(event){
    this.zoomViewer.nativeElement.children[0].style.display = "none";
  }

  public openZoomViewer(){
    this.dialog.open(ProductZoomComponent, {
      data: this.zoomImage,
      panelClass: 'zoom-dialog'
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  } 

  public onSubmit(values:Object):void {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      //email sent
    }
  }

  player: YT.Player;
  //private id: string = 'qDuKsiwS5xw';

    savePlayer (player) {
    this.player = player;
    console.log('player instance', player)
    }
  onStateChange(event){
    console.log('player state', event.data);
  }



  public addToCart(product:Product){
    this.appService.addToCart(product);
  }
  public addToWishList(product:Product){
    this.appService.addToWishList(product);

  }
  openModal(id){
    this.modal.openModal(id);
  }

  closeModal(id){
    this.modal.closeModal(id);
  }


}
```

Comment: What is the error ??

Comment: Please create a stackblitz if possible.

Comment: All I want is to create a popup in mat-card

Comment: this sample https://mde-popover-fnxtpv.stackblitz.io  can help you.

Comment: Not that one @mfatih.. I'm looking for mat-card pop-up which displays video

Comment: As in flipkart you see product mat-card and see the video on it